# How to fix cannot resolve symbol 'setDownloadListener'?

Tags: java, android, web, webview, download

I am preparing a webView APP, so I was trying to enable file download in it but the solution results into a problem, the setDownloadListener is colored in red and when I hover over it I see the message cannot resolve symbol '`setDownloadListener`'

Here is the sample codes I have in my android studio

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
    public void onDownloadStart(String s, String s1, String s2,String s3, long l){
       //Other codes
    }
});
```

The line `webView.setDownloadListener`
gives an error cannot resolve symbol 'setDownloadListener' and `DownloadListener()` gives an error "Make 'DownloadListener' return 'void'"

also the arguments or parameters of `onDownloadStart` gives an error message "Identifier expected, expected ;"

The solution I tried is "Invalidate and Restart", but still the problem exists

Please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: `finalStrings1, finalStrings2, final Strings3` you forgot the types here, for one.

Comment: Sorry, Federico I could not understand what you mean, that I forgot the types, can you show me how to rewrite what I have forgotten ?

Comment: `public void onDownloadStart(String s, String finalStrings1, String finalStrings2, String Strings3, long l)` is the correct signature for that method. I suggest you review whatever guide, tutorial, book you're using to learn java. In this specific case, the part(s) about defining methods.

Comment: I have tried the solution you have recommended but another error results "Expression Expected"

Comment: Please update your question with the correction you made (after the current content of your question).